# FontAwesomeKit - 'NSInvalidArgumentException' iOS 7.1.1

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, nsattributedstring, font-awesome

I'm using cool lib **FontAwesomeKit** (https://github.com/PrideChung/FontAwesomeKit) for my new iOS app. But I'm stuck with strange exception it's throwing only on Release mode and my iPhone with iOS 7.1.1.

It looks like:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', 
reason: 'NSConcreteMutableAttributedString addAttribute:value:range:: nil value'
```

When I test in simulator (both DEBUG and RELEASE) and iPhone (DEBUG) everything works fine, iPhone (RELEASE) crashes.

This workaround didn't help - https://github.com/PrideChung/FontAwesomeKit/blob/master/KnownIssues.md

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

The problem was in my code and `__weak` reference:

```
__weak UIColor *menuColor = [UIColor colorWithHexString:@"#636577"];
__weak UIColor *menuColorHover = [UIColor colorWithHexString:@"#3D3F52"];
CGFloat icon_size = 25.5f;

for (UIButton *button in self.buttons) {
    if ([button.titleLabel.text isEqualToString:@"Feed"]) {
        FAKFoundationIcons *feedIcon = [FAKFoundationIcons homeIconWithSize:icon_size];

        [feedIcon addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:menuColor];
        [button setImage:[feedIcon imageWithSize:CGSizeMake(icon_size, icon_size)] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        [feedIcon addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:menuColorHover];
        [button setImage:[feedIcon imageWithSize:CGSizeMake(icon_size, icon_size)] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    }
```

Comment: Symbolicate the crash report and see where in your app it is crashing.

Comment: I see where it is ``[feedIcon addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:menuColor];``

Comment: It would seem that `menuColor` is `nil`. You need to determine why.

Comment: yeah.. that's because I defined it as weak - ``__weak UIColor *menuColor = [UIColor colorWithHexString:@"#636577"];``..

Comment: but it worked well on simulator and iphone debug, could you explain why I can't to use weak here? I thought it will save some memory.. the code looked as follows ``__weak UIColor *menuColor = [UIColor colorWithHexString:@"#636577"]; CGFloat icon_size = 25.5f; for (UIButton *button in self.buttons) { FAKFoundationIcons *feedIcon = [FAKFoundationIcons homeIconWithSize:icon_size]; [feedIcon addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:menuColor];``

Comment: It would be better to edit your question instead. It would be more readable.

Comment: updated, take a look please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need `__weak` there.

As you said in the comments, it worked in debug builds since no optimizations were in place, but in release builds the compiler decided to optimize away the weak references, leaving you with `nil` passed as an argument.

Just get rid of the unnecessary `__weak` modifier and you'll be good.